# why we cannot use public/protected/private keywords in the constructor of C#

Tags: c#, typescript, constructor

In TypeScript I can write the following code, which will accept a constructor argument `environment` and make that available as a field in the class:

```
class Example {

    constructor(private Environment environment) {

    }

    public get Name(): string { return this.environment.Name; }

}
```

And in C# the equivalent behaviour can be produced with the following code. Here I have to manually create the field and assign its value from the constructor parameter:

```
class Example
{

    public Example(Environment environment)
    {
        this.enviornment = enviornment;
    }

    private Environment environment;
    public string Name => this.environment.Name;

}
```

Why doesn't C# have similar functionality to TypeScript, such that it could be written like so?:

```
class Example
{

    public Example(private Environment environment)
    {
    }

    public string Name => this.environment.Name;

}
```

Why can't C# do the same thing?

Comment: I'm going to go with "because it can't."

Comment: This feature is available in typescript but not in C#

Comment: C# doesn't have feature, you can have private constructor, please refer Microsoft documentation for further reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors

Comment: @BhasyakaruluKottakota I fail to see how that's useful.

Comment: Possible technical reason: a constructor is just a special kind of method - specifically, the _name_ is special. Even ` : this()` and ` :base()` are compiled as method calls to the other constructor. Therefore, adding such functionality to .NET languages would require separating regular methods and constructors at the CLR level - separation that currently doesn't exist. Of course, I guess you could do this as syntactic sugar in the way that auto-properties have auto-generated backing fields, but I guess Microsoft don't see the cost benefit for them as a company.

Comment: Anyway, I feel that "why haven't Microsoft included feature X in C#?" questions are something of a poor fit for [SO] since it asks us to know what Microsoft are thinking, and unless one of the MS .NET team are here to answer then we can only speculate.

Comment: The list of possible things that could be done is infinite, therefore it is better to ask about things that have been done, as it is much, much smaller.

Answer (score -1):

Unless the class is static, classes without constructors are given a public parameterless constructor by the C# compiler in order to enable class instantiation.
A Class Can have a public/private/protected access modifiers.

You can prevent a class from being instantiated by making the constructor private, as follows:

```
class NLog
{
    // Private Constructor:
    private NLog() { }

    public static double e = Math.E;  //2.71828...
}
```

Now in your mentioned example above :

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel(
            MainWindow view,
            public Enviornment enviornment)
        {

        }

        public string Name => this.enviornment.Name;
    }
```

There the MainWindowViewModel constructor is having parameters and you can not define parameter as public inside a function definition,  below is the correct way to approach what you want to do :

```
public class Environment {
    private string _SomeInfo;
    public String SomeInfo 
      { 
        get { return _SomeInfo; }
        set 
        { 
          if (value != null)
          {
            _SomeInfo = value; 
          }
        }
      }
}

public class Program : Environment
{
    public int VariableInfomration;

    private void program(int Data,string information){
       Data = 0;
       information ="";
       VariableInfomration = 1;
    }

    public string Name => SomeInfo;      

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Example Constructor");
    }
}
```

If there is still something that you have  not understood or I have misunderstood because of your question and its details are not well written hence, I hope it will help you

Comment: OP's question is perfectly well written IMHO. If you're familiar with TypeScript, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Rather than making the answer a negative kindly edit the question, in a better-detailed way so people can help you understand and as well there is provided information about the detailed answer I have given with approach what he should have done rather than not learning from it try to improve your question I would suggest, help the guy in learning something new from it.

Comment: Why are you referring to it as my question? It's not my question.

Comment: And downvoting incorrect answers is the correct way to indicate to other readers that they are not correct.

Comment: The given explanation is correct, but I've edited OP's question to be clearer for you. I'm sorry that you're not familiar with how [SO] works yet, but don't take downvotes personally. It simply means that the answer is not a good fit for the question.

Comment: Anyway, you shouldn't answer questions like this anyway because they are not a good fit for [SO] as I explained in my comment on the question. They're asking "Why doesn't feature X exist in C#?" which, in reality, only Microsoft can answer. We can only ever speculate.

Comment: Well,  I appreciate you took my advice and tried to help the person as well as understanding how to write the question.

Comment: Honestly, if you have experience with both C# _and_ TypeScript, the question was fine as written (OP correctly tagged it as both C# and TypeScript). If you are unfamiliar with TypeScript, then it might be unclear what OP expects by having a modifier on a constructor argument. If you haven't tried TypeScript, I recommend it. In a lot of ways it makes a lot of the problems of Javascript go away.

Answer (score -2):

According to syntax of the constructor or any method in c#, We can only defines datatype and variable name as parameter.
Access modifiers are defined at class level.

Eg. Class Environment can be made public but when you define parameter of Type Environment,

You need to pass only class name and variable name in the constructor.

Comment: I don't think this is the "why" OP is looking for.